# app.config file is missing in Azure worker role deployed from Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've been investigating a bug where the worker role kept recycling after deployment from TFService. Turns out the worker recycled because the app.config file was missing. (myworkername.dll.config) It was missing in the WA package created by TFService. However, when built locally the config file is available in the package.

The question is why would TFService skip config file from adding it to azure package? Logs show that this file isn't being copied when the actual azure package is created. Am I doing something wrong or it's again TFSService bug? I've tried recreating a new worker role and azure projects from scratch. I tried copying "ContinuesDeployment.xaml" template from another project where it works... Any ideas?

The following is msbuild script generated and executed by VSOnline:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger
"C:\a\src\Kloud\Azure\Media\Media.sln" /nr:False /fl
/flp:"logfile=C:\a\src\Kloud\Azure\Media\Media.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal"
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:TargetProfile=Development
/t:Kloud_Media_WindowsAzureService:Publish /p:PublishDir="C:\a\bin/app.publish/"
/t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=Development /p:Configuration=Development /m
/p:OutDir="C:\a\bin\\" /p:Configuration="Development" /p:Platform="Any CPU"
/p:VCBuildOverride="C:\a\src\Kloud\Azure\Media\Media.sln.Any CPU.Development.vsprops"
/dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\lightrail\Services\Mms\BuildProvisioner\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/5626;IgnoreDuplicateProjects=False;InformationNodeId=15;TargetsNotLogged=GetNativeManifest,GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems,GetTargetPath;TFSUrl=https://kloud.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\lightrail\Services\Mms\BuildProvisioner\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;"
/p:BuildId="ea0dbce4-2b3d-4cca-8b3d-d89eff06466f,vstfs:///Build/Build/5626"
/p:BuildLabel="kloudmediadev_CD_20131212.4" /p:BuildTimestamp="Thu, 12 Dec 2013 06:32:35 GMT"
/p:BuildSourceVersion="Lkloudmediadev_CD_20131212.4@$/Kloud"
/p:BuildDefinition="kloudmediadev_CD"
```

Comment: Have you tried building your package from the command line with MSBuild?  If look at the diagnostic log in the browser you can see the MSBuild command line that is getting run.

The package is created by MSBuild and we don't have any influence of how that process works.

Comment: Do you know which build xaml you are using? Which version of Visual Studio, Which version of the Azure SDK?

Comment: I created a vanilla Cloud Service project using VS2013 and SDK 2.2 with a web and worker role.  I checked it into a project in my account and built it with the Azure*Deployment.11.xaml template and the cspack did have my WorkerRole1.dll.config.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried building with msbuild. It was fine. However, I used less arguments. I'll try to run the full command later. It's VS2013, Azure SDK 2.2. How do I check build xaml version? I've tried using template from another project (different tenant) where everything worked fine; still the same result.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I've updated the question with a relevant msbuild script. Please let me know if you see a problem.

Comment: can you email me at chrispat at Microsoft dot com?  There has got to be something going on with this solution specifically and maybe with closer inspection we can figure it out.